# How to run a C++ Program interactive using external tools in gedit

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gedit

I'm trying to run my C++ program interactively straight in gedit using external tools.

I've already written a Python tool for compiling it, but when using `os.system("./program.out")` all input for the program is set to 0 (but it is getting executed right, though).

Since using Python for executing it interactive would be rather difficult, im looking for another solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

filename = os.getenv("GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME")
fout = "%s%s"%(filename[:len(filename)-4], ".out") #

os.system("c++ -o %s %s" % (fout,filename))

os.system("./%s" % fout)
```

the compiling works flawless, but ./program.out also doesn't give the wanted result using bash.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does GEdit somehow provide a terminal where you *could* provide input?

Comment: My first reaction: but, why? do you hate IDEs for some reason?

Comment: @DavisHerring good point! ive actually found something, but its.... yea... ill post the answer :)

Comment: @LeDYoM yes! i just dont like them because they are not really in place and ofcourse you need additional software. I just want to work with minimum / my own tools^^

Comment: @LarsMüller: Note that more powerful editors like Emacs actually **do** provide a terminal that can be used for such purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is another solution:

I can just use `echo 3 2 1 | ./program.out` in the tool

this makes everything way more easy

Answer (score 0):

I guess i've found an answer. It may not be the most beautiful solution, but it works.

When defining a tool you can choose the input in a drop-down menu, there is an option for selected text as input.

So for example, if you have a program that reads 3 variables from stdin, you can add a comment to your code like `//1 3 2`, only select the numbers and then run your tool.
These numbers will be used as input in this order, somehow it only works with spaces.

A cruel way of implementing this would be to scan for input calls in the source code and ask for them via zenity in the gedit tool, i guess.